# How do I speed up iOS transitions and segues?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

Is it possible to set a property application-wide to double the speed of transitions within an iOS app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Application-wide?

Try setting the speed property on the backing layer for your view controllers' content views. speed=2 would be double-speed. You could probably set this in the viewDidLoad method for all your view controllers.

You might also be able to create a custom subclass of UIWindow, and have that window object set the speed property on it's view layer to 2.0 in a bottleneck method like makeKeyWindow. You'd need to make all your app's UIWindow objects use your custom class. I'd have to do some digging to figure out how to do that.

##Edit:

Or, better idea, set `self.window.layer.speed = 2.0` in your app delegate after creating the window, as suggested by @Costique in the comment below.

Note that this approach will speed up ALL animations, not just transitions and segues. If you only want to speed up segues you would have to figure out how to target just those animations. I'd have to think about that.

Comment: Subclassing `UIWindow` is not necessary. You can just do `self.window.layer.speed = 2.0f` in your app delegate right after creating the window.

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not have a simple way to change that since it would make transitions too heterogenous amongst different apps. You could double the layer's speed, but that would mess up the timing on the rest of your animations. The best way is to implement your own transition using a category on UIViewControler.

**UIViewController+ShowModalFromView.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface UIViewController (ShowModalFromView)
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController fromView:(UIView *)view;
@end
```

**UIViewController+ShowModalFromView.m**

```
#import "UIViewController+ShowModalFromView.h"

@implementation UIViewController (ShowModalFromView)

- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController fromView:(UIView *)view {
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

// Add the modal viewController but don't animate it. We will handle the animation manually
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];

// Remove the shadow. It causes weird artifacts while animating the view.
CGColorRef originalShadowColor = modalViewController.view.superview.layer.shadowColor;
modalViewController.view.superview.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

// Save the original size of the viewController's view    
CGRect originalFrame = modalViewController.view.superview.frame;

// Set the frame to the one of the view we want to animate from
modalViewController.view.superview.frame = view.frame;

// Begin animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^{
                     // Set the original frame back
                     modalViewController.view.superview.frame = originalFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Set the original shadow color back after the animation has finished
                     modalViewController.view.superview.layer.shadowColor = originalShadowColor;
                 }];
}

@end
```

This can easily be changed to use whatever animated transition you want. Hope this helps!