# Why isn't my rx tableview instantly responsive?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, rx-swift

I have created a `tableView` using `rx swift` and it works fine save for one thing: if I press a `cell` as soon as I enter the `view` nothing happens. I added a print in `.modeSelected` and it didn't register. If I wait approximately half a second to a second, then press again, it works fine. This makes the user experience feel like you have to double-tap for the action to take effect.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.rx.modelSelected(SettingsTableViewCellViewModel.self).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] cellViewModel in
            print("THIS TRIGGERS ONLY IF YOU CLICK AFTER 0.5-1 SEC")
            //STUFF HAPPENS
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

As `modeSelected` is inside the `didSet` of the `tableView` I know that the `tableView` is done with its thing and all the data is available. I tried setting `tableView.delaysContentTouches` to `false` and made sure that `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled` was set to `true`.

This is how the content that is accepted:

```
func reloadContent() {
    let allContent = [SettingsTableViewCellViewModel(title: "active_errors".localized(),
                                                     segue: "ErrorsSegue",
                                                     shouldBeShown: { return DoorConnectionStatus.connected == self.statusRelay?.value.status }),
                      SettingsTableViewCellViewModel(title: "events".localized(),
                                                     segue: "EventStatusSegue",
                                                     shouldBeShown: { return DoorConnectionStatus.connected == self.statusRelay?.value.status }),
                      SettingsTableViewCellViewModel(title: "event_log".localized(),
                                                     segue: "EventLogSegue",
                                                     shouldBeShown: { return DoorConnectionStatus.connected == self.statusRelay?.value.status }),
                          
                      //...and it keeps going
    ]
    content.accept(allContent.filter { $0.shouldBeShown() == true })
}
```

And then bound to the `tableView`:

```
viewModel.content.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: SettingsTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: SettingsTableViewCell.self)) { _, data, cell in
    cell.viewModel = data
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Does this happen every time, or only the first time after you start up the app? Is it only when you are using the simulator or also on a device?

Comment: @DanielT. Yes, every time I exit the view and reenter I experience the problem. If I wait a sec then there's no issue. This is also consistent. I only run it on device as the app won't work on a simulator.

Comment: I just setup a sample app that has all the code you wrote above in it. I am not experiencing the problem you say you are having. Your problem isn't this code but somewhere else. Try to write a minimal _compilable_ sample that has the problem you are experiencing and update your question. Likely, you will find the problem while you are making the sample.

Comment: @DanielT Thanks for testing it. I'll try as you suggested and get back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm why are you using `didSet` on the `tableView` property to do this?
Why not use `viewDidLoad`?
Something like:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rx.modelSelected(SettingsTableViewCellViewModel.self)
      .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] cellViewModel in })
    
}
```

Comment: To make sure the tableView is set up properly before you can click the cells. Sure, you can put it in viewDidLoad as well. In any case, it doesn't address the issue at hand in any way.

Comment: Did you try it? Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but the problem persisted. Thanks though :)

Comment: Then the issue is somewhere else. Show how you bind the array of `SettingsTableViewCellViewModel` to the tableView please

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some investigation it turns out that this issue is simply due to to the `viewController` transition animation not being completed. It looks like it's done, but if I take a very close look I can see that it hasn't completed. It seems that the animation slows down a bit by the very end, so what happens is that when I click the `tableView` the animation is still ongoing and so the `cells` are unclickable. This becomes apparent when I turn off the animation. Now all the `cells` are clickable instantaneously.

The problem han be handled by turning the animation off or by setting
`self.window?.layer.speed = 2.0` or whatever (this is global though). Ref: [How do I speed up iOS transitions and segues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018116/how-do-i-speed-up-ios-transitions-and-segues)